# How to display a success popup at top of screen after pressing submit button in .NET MVC?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have built a simple CRUB application using .NET MVC. It is made up of a home page that displays a table of data from a SQL Server DB. The index page has a "create new" button that take the user to a Create page. From here the user can input the details and create a new record.

What I would like is that when the user clicks the create/submit button they are taken back to the index page and a success popup appears at the top of the page saying the record was created successfully.

Is there features in .NET MVC to achieve this or do I need to use something like JavaScript?

Here is the Create HTML

```
@model LS_Position.Models.Job_Lookup_PositionType

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Job_Lookup_PositionType</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    <!-- Hidden field for the PositionID - No need to display this field-->
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PositionID)

    <!-- Name field-->
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- JobDescURL field-->
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.JobDescURL, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.JobDescURL, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.JobDescURL, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- UseCrewType field-->
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UseCrewType, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="checkbox">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UseCrewType)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UseCrewType, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- IsValid field-->
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsValid, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="checkbox">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IsValid)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsValid, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--  Comments field-->
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Comments, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Comments, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Comments, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- OtherHTML field-->
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OtherHTML, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OtherHTML, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OtherHTML, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Here are the methods in the Controller

```
       // GET: Position/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Position/Create
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Job_Lookup_PositionType position)
        {
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add insert logic here
                using (DBModels db = new DBModels())
                {
                    db.Job_Lookup_PositionType.Add(position);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Both ways work. You can use Javascript or you can use ViewBag to pass your message to the posted page.

If you will use ViewBag, you can use the alert of boostrap which you can find here:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/alerts/

If you will use Javascript, you can use Toastr library:

https://codeseven.github.io/toastr/

If you don't want to postback to new page, you can also use Json by using Sweetalert:

https://sweetalert2.github.io/

I used most of them and they are definitely great based on our experience.

Comment: Thanks but how do I add this functionality to my code? :)